# Hide language default on url address bar in Angular 6

Tags: angular, router, angular6

I'm a newbie and I have a problem with router in Angular 6. 
I have three languages: en, de, fr. So now, my url on address bar is:

- **localhost:4200/en/home**
- **localhost:4200/de/home**
- **localhost:4200/fr/home**

But I want with En(default language), my url should be like this:

- **localhost:4200/home**

And the rest is:

- **localhost:4200/de/home**
- **localhost:4200/fr/home**

This is my config routes:

```
 const routes: Routes = [
     {
        path: ':lang/home',
        component: LandingPageComponent,
        children: LandingPagePageRoutes
     },
     {
        path: ':lang/product',
        component: ProductSinglePageComponent,
        children: ProductPageRoutes
     },
     {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: `/${LANG}/home`,
        pathMatch: 'full'
     },
     {
        path: '**',
        redirectTo: `/${LANG}/home`,
     }
 ];
```

Can we do that? And if yes, please send me some example for that? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because Angular doesn't allow a redirect from another redirect, one way I think you can do this is, in the constructor of your root component, that's probably `app.component.ts`, you can get the url of the page when the app launches and then redirect to `localhost:4200/home` if it is `localhost:4200/en/home`. Your code will look something like this.

app.component.ts

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

constructor(private router: Router) {
  if(this.router.url === "/en/home"){
        router.navigateByUrl('/home')
    }
 }
```

Then in your routing module, you should have a url that matches `/home`

Something like this.

```
 {
    path: 'home',
    component: EnglishLandingPageComponent
 }
```

Comment: Hi @Alf Moh, thanks for you solutions. So for each route, we will define again url. Is it right?

Comment: `router.url` gives you the current url. Since app.component.ts is the component for your home page, anytime anyone visits the homepage and the person has English as their language thereby making the url look like this (`localhost:4200/en/home`), the constructor will be called and the logic inside will run causing a redirection to `localhost:4200/home`

Comment: I got it. Thanks @Alf Moh

Comment: Happy to have helped :-)